# Formatting Hex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

How can I format a hex to be displayed always with 4 digits in javascript?

For example, I converting a decimal to hex :

```
port = 23
function d2h(d) {return (+d).toString(16);}
d2h(port)
```

I am successfully able to convert "23" to the hex value "17". However, I would like to be formatted like this "0017" (with four digits -- appending 0's before the 17).

All information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an easy way:

```
return ("0000" + (+d).toString(16)).substr(-4);
```

Or:

```
return ("0000" + (+d).toString(16)).slice(-4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf
[http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf [Wayback Machine March 2021]](https://web.archive.org/web/20200428204520/http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)

(Refers to an Open Source JavaScript library called `sprintf.js`, at https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js)

I havent tried it yet but something like this should work:

```
sprintf("%.4X", d)
```